# Automation test for File Upload using Selenium behaves in different way in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer, webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to test file upload feature by automation testing using Selenium webdrivers in C#. It works fine using Mozilla Firefox browser, but it behaves in a different way when I use Internet explorer. This is how my HTML looks like:

```
<input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" class="Uploader">
```

I am using below code to have the file upload done.

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); // have the recent IE webdrivers added as reference to the project
driver.FindElement(By.Id("fileUpload")).SendKeys("Path where file is located");
```

This works fine in Firefox browser (InitializeDriver.driver = new FirefoxDriver();), but when I try to use the code for Internet explorer, instead of uploading a file from local path, it clicks the browse button and opens the window from the local folder to select a file (similar to how we browse and select a file for uploading) and stops there and file upload is not happening. I am not sure whether we can select the file from this window using automation. I looked into many posts and most of the posts suggest to use SendKeys which I am using already, but experiencing this kind of behavior in Internet Explorer. I am trying to test using IE latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Get v3.4 of the Selenium IE driver.   [Issue 3587](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3587) discusses the issue.  v3.4 was released late last week and has fixed most of my issues.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out and can provide an update on it.